# How does YouTube create this dropdown effect?

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, dropdown

I'm seeing this dropdown on Youtube from [here](https://www.youtube.com/user/phpacademy/videos?flow=grid). How does YouTube create that dropdown effect "Date added(newest-oldest)."

**Features of this dropdown:**

- Styling
- Links on dropdown selection

Thanks for any help given...

Comment: I'm not sure, what are you asking for? I mean are you asking how you could integrate such a dropdown (then there is stuff around, like bootstrap: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns ). Or do you want to do it by yourself (then try it and ask a more precise question when you're stuck).

Comment: @Py. Bootstrap sounds like an excellent idea for a dropdown like YouTube. I will install and use Bootstrap and comment if I have any problems. Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot custom the style for the options in dropdown box, but you can create a fake dropdown box with other DOM elements, and handle click event by jQuery.

Check this:  
or Bootstrap MultiSelect :

What bootstrap multiselect does is, it hides the original `<select>` element, then create a `<button>` as the selector and a `<ul>` as the dropdown list. So you can style it with css. Once you change an option, the original `<select>` will change to the same option. It is helpful when you are dealing with `<form>`.